# Using curly brackets instead of make_pair giving error

Tags: c++, stl, lower-bound

It gives `no instance of overloaded function "lower_bound" matches the argument list` error. I don't understand this behavior as curly brackets work fine in general while making a pair.

Using curly brackets:

```cpp
vector<pair<int, int>> a;
auto ptr = lower_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), {2, 3});
```

Using make pair:

```cpp
vector<pair<int, int>> a;
auto ptr = lower_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), make_pair(2, 3));
```

Comment: How could a compiler deduce `std::pair` from `{2, 3}` even in principle? Note that the iterator type doesn't participate in this deduction: `template<class ForwardIt, class T> ForwardIt lower_bound( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value );`.

Comment: @Evg so, do I need to cast it like `std::pair<int, int>{2, 3}`?

Comment: You could say `std::pair(2, 3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler has no possiblility to deduce `{2, 3}` to `std::pair<int, int>` in this context. See the declaration of [`lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

```
template< class ForwardIt, class T >
ForwardIt lower_bound( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value );
```

Compiler cannot assume that `T` should be equal to `decltype(*first)`, because it doesn't have to be the case - it's only required that they are comparable.

You need to disambiguate by actually naming the type you want to use - either by calling `std::make_pair(2, 3)` or by creating a temporary: `std::pair{2, 3}` (template arguments can be ommitted since C++17, for earlier standard you need `std::pair<int, int>{2, 3}` or `make_pair`).

Answer (score 2):

The [answer provided by Yksisarvinen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69417171/10871073) explains why your first code snippet won't compile (i.e., why the compiler can't properly deduce the type of your third argument to `lower_bound`); it also offers two methods to solve the issue, both of which are eminently sensible.

However, there is a *third* possibility – though whether or not it is 'sensible' is a subjective call. So, for the sake of completeness, I shall  illustrate that method here …

You can *explicitly* provide the template parameters for `lower_bound` in your call, which enables the compiler to correctly interpret the type of the third argument:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    vector<pair<int, int>> a;
    auto ptr = lower_bound< decltype(a.begin()),pair<int,int> >(a.begin(),a.end(),{2,3});
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the specification for `lower_bound` (taken from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)):

> ```
> template< class ForwardIt, class T >
> ForwardIt lower_bound( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value );
> ```

Thus, in the code I have provided, we have explicitly specified the types of both `ForwardIt` **and** `class T` (as `pair<int,int>`), so the third function argument will be *known* to be a `const` reference to such a type, and *deduction* of that type will not be required.